# Azure VM Failover

Tags: virtual-machines, azure, failover

Do Azure VM's have built in failover or is it necessary to spin up additional appliances to deal with failover? I have also been looking at Site Recovery as a service in Azure - is it common to use Site Recovery instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Depends what you mean by failover. Azure deals with hardware failure, so if a host machine fails your VM will be restarted on another host. However, this will incur an interruption in service, as will reboots for host updates etc. Microsoft recommend having at least 2 instance of any VM, and this is required if you want the 99.99% up time SLA.

Site recovery lets you replicate on prem, or Azure VM's into Azure for DR purposes it's not really intended for providing fault tolerance.
There are other services such as Azure Traffic Manager  which will allow you to distribute your VM's over multiple regions and direct traffic to them as required, but ultimately you still need to build your fault tolerant solution in the infrastructure and in your application.